# iOS UITextField in UINavigationItem

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uitextfield, uinavigationitem

I need to put a `UITextField` in a `UINavigationItem` and have it take the entire width minus the margins. I'm setting the TitleView of the `NavigationItem` but cannot find a way to have it take the entire width. I've tried using `this.NavigationItem.SizeToFit()` but that simply reduces the width to fit the content. I've also tried manually setting the width, but this solution doesn't work when I rotate or when there is a Left or Right `BarButtonItem`... Is there a way to automatically adjust the width of the title view to take all the remaining space without using constraints? I've tried using constraints but I get warnings for conflicting constraints.

Note: I'm using Xamarin in C# but a solution in Objective-C is fine by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set its frame something like this worked for me

```
CGFloat margin = 20;
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width - (2* margin), 21.0)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = textField;
```

**Edit:**

You need to update frame on rotation, you can do that in `viewDidLayoutSubView` and set frame by updated width.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CGFloat margin = 20;
    self.textFi[![enter image description here][1]][1]eld.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width - (2* margin), 21.0)
}
```

Or add Auto layout constraint and pin `texField` to `superView` from left and right, and auto layout will handle rotation for you as well.

Below are the screen shots in both orientation with left right navigation item

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's fine but it doesn't work when rotating or when I have other items in the NavigationItem

Comment: You can update its frame in viewDidLayoutSubView or you use auto layout, updated my answer

Comment: Alright, now I still don't know what to do when I have something in the LeftBarButtonItem! I could get the width of that, do multiplications and stuff but it seems to me there's got to be a way to do this automagically...

Comment: it will handle it self.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusBarOrientationChange:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];
[self statusBarOrientationChange:nil];
}

- (void)statusBarOrientationChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
self.navigationItem.titleView = textField;
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```